# Servidor Websocket - Erro no comando npm server.js

Tags: node.js, websocket

Tentei executar o comando `npm server.js` e ele me volta esse erro:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
>           at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>           at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
>           at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
>           at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
>           at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
>           at Object. (C:\xampp\htdocs\123\server.js:15:6)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>           at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
>           at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
>           at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

**servidor.js:**

```
var http= require('http').createServer(function (req,res) {res.end()})
var io = require('socket.io')(http)
var Redis = require('ioredis')
var redis = new Redis(6379,'127.0.0.1')

redis.psubscribe('*', function (){

  redis.on('pmessage', function (channel, mensage, pattern){
    console.log(channel, mensage, pattern);
  })

}
)

http.listen(3000, function (){
  console.log('Listeining on porta 3000')
})
```

Já instalei as dependências `npm install socket.io ioredis`.

Alguém pode me ajudar.

Comment: Esse erro indica que você já está utilizando a porta `3000`. Então você pode tentar a) mudar a porta, b) descobrir a aplicação que está utilizando esta porta

Comment: @Sorack, sou novo em node.js como faço para alterar a porta ou saber oq esta utilisando a porta?

Comment: Na linha `http.listen(3000, function (){` troque o `3000` para outro número.

Comment: @Sorack obg me ajudou muito